# Couldn't find pygtk because of PATH order? Where is default PATH defined?

Tags: linux, path, ordering

I installed a program that imported pygtk.  It worked fine in my environment, but a "blank" environment (e.g. a new user) wouldn't work.

I determined it was due to PATH.  The resolution was baffling though.

My PATH was set as thus:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin
PATH=$PATH:/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin  #******
PATH=$PATH:/sbin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
PATH=$PATH:/home/td69386/bin
```

Default was set as thus:

```
PATH=/usr/lib/qt-3.3/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin  #*****
PATH=$PATH:/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
PATH=$PATH:/sbin
PATH=$PATH:/home/td69386/bin
```

The only difference is order.  Specifically I put `/usr/bin` above `/usr/local/bin`.

Without this tiny change the program errors with:

```
    import pygtk
ImportError: No module named pygtk
```

I didn't think PATH ordering was that important, but apparently it is.  Why would the system care this much?  Is it finding and trying to execute the program before it's found pygtk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of the PATH can be quite important: when you run a program, the shell searches for the program name in each of the components of your path, starting from the first. If two programs of the same name exist in two of the paths (for whatever reason) it will use the one it finds first. It seems in your case that you do in fact have two copies of some program, although I don't know if it is python or something else like a program that tells python where to find components, etc.

Comment: Ah, it *stops* searching once its found a match.  For some reason I'm thinking it'd keep going, but that's a bit silly in retrospect; dunno why I though it'd be like that.  Thanks!